# Urban Airship triggers delegate functions on some devices but not on others?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, push, urbanairship.com

I'm testing with two iPhones. Both have the same version of iOS, 11.2.2, the latest one. They're both running the exact same version of the app. They have both given the same permissions for both notifications and background app refresh. Everything in the certificate is provisioned correctly.

This is an example of what I'm sending:

```html
{
  "audience": {
    "named_user": "4"
  },
  "notification": {
    "ios" : {
      "content-available": true,
      "priority": 5
    }
  },
  "device_types": ["ios"]
}
```

With one iPhone both the `receivedForegroundNotification` delegate function and `receivedBackgroundNotification` delegate function is triggered appropriately depending on whether or not the app is in the foreground or background.

However, with the other device, neither of the Urban Airship delegate functions are triggered. The only thing that does work is that when I send a simple "Hello" alert it comes through just fine with the app in the background, though it never triggers any of the delegates, so I can't use it to sync data in the background.

As far as Urban Airship is telling me from the dashboard, both of the named users' devices (they're different named users) have given all green consent.

I don't know what else could be wrong. I can post some of my code if you guys want but given that it works fine on one device and not on another, I can't imagine that's the issue. Any help would really be much appreciated. I'm starting to give up on Urban Airship as a push provider but it would require a fair amount of work to transition to another one and I'm not happy with most of their privacy policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Urban Airship suggested I try to use their sample app to replicate the behavior, and I was not able to replicate it. So it **was** a problem with my code. It seems like the only thing I had changed to fix it is that I had some code that was asking for permission from the user to push notifications both through Urban Airship and directly through UNUserNotification. I got rid of the latter part, and since then the issue is gone. Still weird that this would only cause problems on some devices and not on others, but I'm glad it's fixed!